# I have a 3d solid drawing I need to import from autoCAD

Tags: import

I am trying to use Blender as a way of improving the look of our 3D drawings.
I have tried to research this and have managed to save original as a DXF then import to blender, however it is only showing as wireframes not as solid 3D objects!

Thank you

---

Yes sure,
I scale the drawing down in AutoCAD first and then save as DXF 
and this is the result when imported into blender[image]

Whats interesting is when I import the DXF back into CAD I get the same wire frame result!

I've attached what the origonal AutoCAD file looks like and shows what I'm trying to achieve.[image: THis is the Original CAD file not the DXF]

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62606/can-i-import-autodesk-inventor-2016-models

Comment: Can you post pictures to show us what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

When importing from autocad to blender, usualy it is  pieces of furniture for me, i'm using stl format and downscale it to fit units and view. Never using dxf because having problems with it.